# blazor why i can pass void to component and not action?

Tags: c#, .net, dialog, delegates, blazor

i have some blazor component dialog as

```
 <MudDialog>
<DialogContent>
    <MudText>@ContentText</MudText>
</DialogContent>
<DialogActions>
    <MudButton OnClick="Cancel">@CancelButtonText</MudButton>
    <MudButton Color="@Color" Variant="Variant.Filled" OnClick="@InvokeOkAction">@ButtonText</MudButton>
</DialogActions>
</MudDialog>

   @code {
    [CascadingParameter] MudDialogInstance? MudDialog { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? ContentText { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? ButtonText { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? CancelButtonText { get; set; } = "Anuluj";
    [Parameter] public Color Color { get; set; }

[Parameter] public Action? OkAction { get; set; }

    private void InvokeOkAction()
    {
        OkAction?.Invoke();
        MudDialog?.Close(DialogResult.Ok(true));
    }


void Cancel() => MudDialog?.Cancel();
```

and now when i want to use it

```
 private void SaveAsProd()
{
    var parameters = new DialogParameters();
    parameters.Add("ContentText", "Do you really want to delete these records?");
    parameters.Add("ButtonText", "Delete");
    parameters.Add("OkAction", okaction!);
    var options = new DialogOptions() { CloseButton = true, MaxWidth = MaxWidth.ExtraSmall };

    DialogService.Show<SimpleDialogComponent>("????", parameters, options);

}
   private  void okaction() { Console.WriteLine("asd");}

   private  Action  okaction2(){ return ()=>  Console.WriteLine("asd");}
```

and i have and issue with passing this action/OkAction
if i pass void `okaction` it works fine
but if i pass it as action  / `okaction2`
i get

```
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
  Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to set property 'OkAction' on object of type 'xx.Client.Components.SimpleDialogComponent'. The error was: Specified cast is not valid.
 System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to set property 'OkAction' on object of type 'xx.Client.Components.SimpleDialogComponent'. The error was: Specified cast is not valid.
 ---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

why is that? canot i pass some action? it would be easier to pass it via lambda even but error is the same?

thanks and regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Parameter] public Action? OkAction { get; set; }
```

OkAction is an Action and expects a method that returns void.

```
private  void okaction() { Console.WriteLine("asd");}
```

is such a method. So `parameters.Add("OkAction", okaction);` works. No need for the `!`

```
private  Action  okaction2(){ return ()=>  Console.WriteLine("asd");}
```

defines a method that returns an Action.

```
parameters.Add("OkAction", okaction2);    // won't work
parameters.Add("OkAction", okaction2());  // should work
```

Comment: thanks. that's so easy now when i understand this.

Comment: i can do also   parameters.Add("OkAction", () => {  Console.WriteLine("asd"); }); but canot   parameters.Add("OkAction",async () => {  Console.WriteLine("asd"); });   is there any way also? or need to be seperate action? there async works :) thanks

Comment: I think you should use EventCallback instead of Action here. It's specific for Blazor.